# How to encrypt or tokenize a username and date token?

Tags: java, .net, token, url-parameters

Need to pass a tokenized (encrypted) username and date from webapp A to webapp B via a url parameter. Something like http://webappB?username=userA&timestamp=13445341313 should be sent as http://webappB?token=geufjsggtj26hjdhcjre87klj3. The receiving webapp B should be able to decode the token into the original parameters.
Which technology offers a simple solution that is available for .NET and java? Thanks

Comment: Please re-title this into a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the solution that I found after some more research.
I chose a very simple symmetric XOR based scramble method in favour of using encryption across platforms.

A piece of code says more than thousand words :

```
// webappA, encode URL parameter
    byte[] userBytes = username.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    //XOR scramble
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[userBytes.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < userBytes.length; i++){
       encrypted[i] = (byte)(userBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i % keyBytes.length]);
    }

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String encoded = encoder.encode(encrypted);

 // webappB, decode the parameter
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] decoded =  decoder.decodeBuffer( encoded );
    //XOR descramble
    byte[] decrypted = new byte[decoded.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++){
       decrypted[i] = (byte)(decoded[i] ^ keyBytes[i % keyBytes.length] );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What you've suggested is very simple and doesn't require including technologies outside of what Java and .NET already offer. **Simply build up an HTTP request, fire it to the right URL, and listen for the response.**

**Class References**

- Java: [HttpURLConnection<sup>Oracle</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
- .NET: [WebRequest<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

If you think you'll be doing more of this, or the data gets more frequent, complex, or structured, I highly recommend the ubiquitous [SOAP<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) protocol for  extensibility and modularity.

Comment: the connection is not the problem. What should I use for encoding/decoding the username and date parameter into a single token that will be sent as a url parameter.